# Trying to define a getter on custom HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to change what is returned when you access the `value` property on this custom element - which extends [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). This would be used for entering currency values. The input would show `1,000.00` (string) but would return `1000` (float) through its `value` property.

Unfortunately, the getter doesn't seem to be executing.

```js
function moneyStringToFloat(value) {
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    value = value / 100;

    return value;
}

class CustomInput extends HTMLInputElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.type = "text";
    }
    
    static get value() {
        return moneyStringToFloat(this.value);
    }
}

customElements.define("custom-input", CustomInput, {extends: "input"});

const customInput = document.querySelector('input#customInput');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

output.textContent = customInput.value;
```

```html
<input is="custom-input"
  id="customInput"
  value="1,000.00">

<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: You are using `static` which is likely what you do not want to use. Furthermore within your `get value()` you most likely want to use `this.getAttribute('value')`.

Comment: Removed the `static` keyword, but now I'm getting `Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion`.

Comment: That is to be expected. Either Hitest's `super.value` or my `this.getAttribute` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I used `super.value`.

Comment: Note that ``extends HTMLInputElement`` will never work on Apple/Safari. Apple has, many moons ago, and rightly so with good arguments, made it very clear they will never implement _Customized Built-In_ elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a static getter. So, It was not worked. Static getters are accessed through the class itself, not through its instances.

Here is updated version of your question.

```html
function moneyStringToFloat(value) {
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    value = value / 100;

    return value;
}

class CustomInput extends HTMLInputElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.type = "text";
    }
    
    get value() {
        return moneyStringToFloat(super.value);
    }
}

customElements.define("custom-input", CustomInput, {extends: "input"});

const customInput = document.querySelector('input#customInput');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

output.textContent = customInput.value;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Your snippet has a problem, though. It's outputting code instead of running it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `extends HTMLInputElement` will never work in Safari, because Apple has, rightly so, argumented they will never implement **Customized Built-In** Elements.

You can use an **Autonomous Element**:

```js
customElements.define("custom-input", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a monetary value"/>`;
    }
    get value() {
      let value = this.querySelector("input").value;
      return (value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) / 100;
    }
});
```

```html
$ <custom-input onchange="alert(this.value)"></custom-input>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.
I was hoping I could make this element behave like the built-in `input[type=date]` or `input[type=number]`, displaying a nice localized format (e.g. `DD/MM/YYYY` or the string `1.234,56`) but always returning a standard format (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD` or the float `1234.56`) when submitted or converted to `FormData`. Using event listeners you can achieve the same effect, but not in the same neat way the built-in elements do.

Comment: The ``input`` inside the Web Components ``innerHTML`` **IS** a native "built-in" input